# what does “the logic is fishier than the handymen”mean？

Tags: expressions

the sentence is cited from *How to Win Every Argument*。I can't find the links between fishier and handymen，and I wonder if there is any saying about the logic of handymen？here are the context：

> No handymen are bakers, and no bakers are fishermen, so no handymen
>   are fishermen.
>   (It seems innocent enough, **but the logic is fishier than the handymen**.
>   If we had used 'tax-dodgers' instead of fishermen, we would
>   have ended up saying 'no handymen are tax-dodgers', which
>   everyone knows is untrue. The fault lies with the two negative
>   premises.)

Answer (score 1):

Fish are slippery, and rotten fish stink.  Thus, "fishy" means "untrustworthy".

In this example, the author is playing with the words "fishy" and "fishermen".  The alleged proof discusses whether-or-not the handymen perform fishing, so in this particular context, these handymen may-or-may-not have something to do with fish.

Comment: thank you， got it. i had been misled by the translator of the book. He

Comment: i should finish the last sentence.The translator translates it into Chinese as这里的逻辑比杂工更靠不住。